# Azure Functions VS Deploy Environment Variables

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm developping the Azure Functions in VS2017. I'm using several environment variables. Is there a way when deploying to have them create when they don't exist.
I understand that they should not be copied (values) each time as on production they will have different values then in dev.
But creating a empty variable would be nice, is there a way or am I doing something wrong. Now I've stored them as indicated in the local file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are usually stored in Application settings on portal, and empty values are not allowed.

As you know there could be difference between production and dev, I recommend you to set Application settings in VS when publishing. VS provides a friendly UI with both remote and local settings, you can choose to insert from local or create new settings.(Note the empty value here means there's no such setting in corresponding environment)

[image]